# How to display array contents in 3 different rows?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to display the contents of an array in three different rows, each row containing 20 characters including the spaces in single row. Here is my below code which works, but displays in a single row. Currently my code gives output in a single div tag. But, I am trying to print the output in 3 different div tags.

PS: How do I break s_char_upper1 array into 3 different rows, with each row containing 20 characters, and display in my html page.I have attached an image for your reference. I am trying to display the page in this format. 
[image: The attached image contains the characters including the spaces. There are 3 different rows, with each row containing 20 characters including the spaces. I am trying to get the output like as shown in the image.]

```js
var charDiv_upperCase1 = document.getElementById("checkChar_upperCase1");
                /* Upper case  */
                var s_char_upper1 = ['&#160;','&#065;', '&#160;','&#066;','&#067;','&#068;', '&#160;','&#069;','&#070;', '&#160;','&#071;','&#072;', '&#160;','&#073;','&#074;', '&#160;','&#075;','&#076;','&#077;', '&#160;', '&#160;', '&#160;','&#078;', '&#079;','&#080;', '&#160;','&#081;', '&#082;','&#083;','&#084;', '&#160;', '&#085;', '&#160;','&#086;','&#087;', '&#160;','&#088;','&#089;', '&#160;','&#090;' '&#160;','&#097;', '&#160;','&#098;','&#099;','&#100;', '&#160;','&#101;','&#102;', '&#160;','&#103;','&#104;', &#160;','&#105;','&#106;', '&#160;','&#107;','&#108;','&#109;', '&#160;'];
                for(var i = 0; i < s_char_upper1.length; i++) {
                    var ele = document.createElement("div");
                    ele.className = "testCode_num";
                    ele.innerHTML = s_char_upper1[i];       
                    charDiv_upperCase1.appendChild(ele);
                }
```

```css
 @font-face{
                    font-family: 'test';
                    src: url('ArialMonospacedMTPro.otf');
                }
    
                .testCode_num {
                    font-family: 'test' !important;
                    height: auto;
                    font-size:26px;
                    display: inline-block;
                }
                .mainDiv {
                    border:1px solid red;
                    display: inline-block;
                }
    
                span{
                    color: #5DADE2;
                }
    
                body {
                    background-color: white;
                    padding-left: 70px;
                }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    
        <head>
    
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Test fonts</title>
           
        </head>
    
        <body>
    
            <h1>Character Alignment for <span>Arial Mono MT Pro</span></h1>
    
            <div id="checkChar_upperCase1" class = 'mainDiv'></div></br>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: check last 8th word in array schar1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not wrap each single character in a `div`, but put 20 characters in one `div`. To make the wrapping happening you need to remove `display: inline-block;` from the CSS for the `testCode_num` class.

You can use `splice` to extract 20 character from the array at a time, and use a `while` loop to make sure you treat all:

```
while (s_char_upper1.length) {
    var ele = document.createElement("div");
    ele.className = "testCode_num";
    ele.innerHTML = s_char_upper1.splice(0, 20).join('');       
    charDiv_upperCase1.appendChild(ele);
}
```

NB: there is a missing comma and missing quote in your array literal.

```js
var charDiv_upperCase1 = document.getElementById("checkChar_upperCase1");
/* Upper case  */
var s_char_upper1 = ['&#160;','&#065;','&#160;','&#066;','&#067;',
                     '&#068;','&#160;','&#069;','&#070;','&#160;',
                     '&#071;','&#072;','&#160;','&#073;','&#074;', 
                     '&#160;','&#075;','&#076;','&#077;','&#160;',
                     '&#160;','&#160;','&#078;','&#079;','&#080;',
                     '&#160;','&#081;','&#082;','&#083;','&#084;',
                     '&#160;','&#085;','&#160;','&#086;','&#087;',
                     '&#160;','&#088;','&#089;','&#160;','&#090;',
                     '&#160;','&#097;','&#160;','&#098;','&#099;',
                     '&#100;','&#160;','&#101;','&#102;','&#160;',
                     '&#103;','&#104;','&#160;','&#105;','&#106;', 
                     '&#160;','&#107;','&#108;','&#109;','&#160;'];
while (s_char_upper1.length) {
    var ele = document.createElement("div");
    ele.className = "testCode_num";
    ele.innerHTML = s_char_upper1.splice(0, 20).join('');       
    charDiv_upperCase1.appendChild(ele);
}
```

```css
/* enable this when you have the font:
@font-face{
    font-family: 'test';
    src: url('ArialMonospacedMTPro.otf');
}
*/
.testCode_num {
    font-family: 'test' !important;
    height: auto;
    font-size:26px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.mainDiv {
    display: inline-block;
}

span{
    color: #5DADE2;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Character Alignment for <span>Arial Mono MT Pro</span></h3>

<div id="checkChar_upperCase1" class = 'mainDiv'></div></br>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

check `count` if the value `20` then append it to html

```js
var charDiv_upperCase1 = document.getElementById("checkChar_upperCase1");
/* Upper case  */
var s_char_upper1 = ['&#160;', '&#065;', '&#160;', '&#066;', '&#067;', '&#068;', '&#160;', '&#069;', '&#070;', '&#160;', '&#071;', '&#072;', '&#160;', '&#073;', '&#074;', '&#160;', '&#075;', '&#076;', '&#077;', '&#160;', '&#160;', '&#160;', '&#078;', '&#079;', '&#080;', '&#160;', '&#081;', '&#082;', '&#083;', '&#084;', '&#160;', '&#085;', '&#160;', '&#086;', '&#087;', '&#160;', '&#088;', '&#089;', '&#160;', '&#090;',
  '&#160;', '&#097;', '&#160;', '&#098;', '&#099;', '&#100;', '&#160;', '&#101;', '&#102;', '&#160;', '&#103;', '&#104;', '&#160;', '&#105;', '&#106;', '&#160;', '&#107;', '&#108;', '&#109;', '&#160;'
];
var count = 0;
var s_chars = [];
for (var i = 0; i < s_char_upper1.length; i++) {
  count++;
  if (count == 20) {
    s_chars.push(s_char_upper1[i]);
    var ele = document.createElement("div");
    ele.className = "testCode_num";
    ele.innerHTML = s_chars.join(' '); // separate with space
    charDiv_upperCase1.appendChild(ele);
    count = 0;
    s_chars = [];
  } else {
    s_chars.push(s_char_upper1[i]);
  }

}
```

```css
 @font-face {
   font-family: 'test';
   src: url('ArialMonospacedMTPro.otf');
 }
 
 .testCode_num {
   font-family: 'test' !important;
   height: auto;
   font-size: 26px;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 
 .mainDiv {
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
 }
 
 span {
   color: #5DADE2;
 }
 
 body {
   background-color: white;
   padding-left: 70px;
 }
```

```html
<h1>Character Alignment for <span>Arial Mono MT Pro</span></h1>

<div id="checkChar_upperCase1" class='mainDiv'></div>
<br>
```

Comment: In your code, you have appended all the characters to a single div tag. What I want is, 1st 20 characters should be displayed in a single div tag, 2nd 20 characters should be displayed in another div tag, which should be displayed below the 1st div tag and so on.

For better understanding, I have attached an image of how the output should be. If you see the image, there are 3 different rows which is nothing but 3 different div tags, all separated by a red border.

1st row: A to M containing spaces.
2nd row: N to Z with spaces.
3rd row: a to m with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < s_char_upper1.length; i++) {
```

change to something like

```
for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    for(var i = 0; i < (s_char_upper1.length)/3; i++) {
```

Do take care where s_char_upper1.length is not multiple of 3

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for spending your time to answer my query. Moreover, I took inputs from your answers and modified my code as per my requirement. Here is my code that I am sharing with you guys.

PS: Please feel free to modify my code and give me inputs on how can I improve more in the below code.

```
<DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test fonts</title>
    <style>
      @font-face{
        font-family: 'test';
        src: url('ArialMonospacedMTPro.otf');
      }

      .testCode_num {
        border: 1px solid red;
        font-family: 'test' !important;
        height: auto;
        font-size:26px;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      body {
        background-color: white;
        padding-left: 70px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Character Alignment for <span>Arial Mono MT Pro</span></h1>

    <div id="checkChar_upperCase1"></div></br>

    <script>
        var charDiv_upperCase1 = document.getElementById("checkChar_upperCase1");
        /* Decimal values of Characters */
        var charDynamicArray = [
          '&#160;', '&#065;', '&#160;', '&#066;', '&#067;', '&#068;', '&#160;', '&#069;', '&#070;', '&#160;', '&#071;', '&#072;', '&#160;', '&#073;', '&#074;', '&#160;', '&#075;', '&#076;', '&#077;', '&#160;', '&#160;', '&#160;', '&#078;', '&#079;', '&#080;', '&#160;', '&#081;', '&#082;', '&#083;', '&#084;', '&#160;', '&#085;', '&#160;', '&#086;', '&#087;', '&#160;', '&#088;', '&#089;', '&#160;', '&#090;', '&#160;', '&#097;', '&#160;', '&#098;', '&#099;', '&#100;', '&#160;', '&#101;', '&#102;', '&#160;', '&#103;', '&#104;', '&#160;', '&#105;', '&#106;', '&#160;', '&#107;', '&#108;', '&#109;', '&#160;', '&#160;', '&#160;', '&#110;', '&#111;', '&#160;', '&#112;', '&#113;', '&#114;', '&#115;', '&#160;', '&#116;', '&#117;', '&#160;', '&#118;', '&#119;', '&#160;', '&#120;', '&#121;', '&#160;', '&#122;'];

        var charArraylength = charDynamicArray.length;
        var rowCount = Math.ceil(charArraylength / 20);
        console.log(rowCount);

        for(var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
          var ele = document.createElement("div");
          var br_ele = document.createElement("br");
          ele.className = "testCode_num";
          ele.innerHTML = charDynamicArray.slice( 20 * i, 20 * (i+1)).join('');
          ele.style.borderColor = "1px red";
          charDiv_upperCase1.appendChild(ele);
          charDiv_upperCase1.appendChild(br_ele);
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```